# Android recording coordinates of the point in screen

Tags: android, touch, point, coordinate

My activity should record the coordinates of a point on the screen, which the user can move. Specifically, the user touches the screen and appears on the item, which will be able to move. When you lift your finger, the coordinates of the point should be recorded.Please for your advice.

Comment: u simply want the touch points on screen?

Comment: what problem you are facing? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** Here is whole simple activity which Toasts the user touch down and touch up co-ordinates

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touch Down x="+x+"  y="+y ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Handle Touch Down
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            //Handle Touch Move
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touch Up x="+x+"  y="+y ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Handle Touch Up
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your type, it's very useful, in my program.

Comment: Is there any way to record the coordinates with time for showing a  playback of the motion path?

Comment: @Mahdi Yes it can be done, But it is not available directly, You will have to store the co-ordinates in ontouch method with the timestamp value of the system...