# Display touch coordinates on screen

Tags: android

My objective is to have the user touch anywhere on the screen, and then to have the touch coordinates appear in a textview on the screen.

This is what I have so far.

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/touchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="To be filled" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Main Activity.java`:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.MyFirstApp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                    return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**SOLVED** My first problem is that on `MainActivity.java`, there is an error on line 18, in the code `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. Researching online, it looks like the way to fix this error is to change `import android.R;` to `import your.application.packagename.R;`. However, I do not have `import android.R;` in my `.java` file. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

**EDIT** Second, the textView only displays the touch coordinates when the first textview is clicked, it does not display the touch coordinates of a touchpoint anywhere on the screen (it only displays the touch coordinates of a touch point on the first text view). How can I change this so that the touch coordinates of anywhere on the screen are displayed?

**Another Edit** One idea I had for the second problem was giving the `LinearLayout` I had an `id`, such as `android:id="@+id/touchLayout"`. I was then planning on modifying the `.java` file as such:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.MyFirstApp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
        final View touchLayout = findViewById(R.id.touchLayout);
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                    return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Try changing the layout file in your java code to activity_main as that is what your xml is called, then test your code

Comment: Yup, it worked! I'll test my code to see if it runs!

Comment: On line 18 where is says: setContentView(R.layout.main); change it too setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) if that is what your layout file is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Would you happen to know how to tackle the second issue I had?

Comment: You may refer to this past solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922650/android-recording-coordinates-of-the-point-in-screen

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the answer I had in the second edit was correct. I simply replaced gave the LinearLayout an id, and replaced the touchView id with the LinearLayout id